# xampp - linking to directory not in root

Tags: apache, xampp

I have just installed xampp and would like to link to some dev websites on a separate(not c) drive.
Previously in IIS, I would add a virtual directory in the default website. How do I do the equivalent in xampp. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399238/how-to-configure-xampp-in-windows-if-project-files-are-not-in-root-directory/9461592#9461592

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [VHosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/), or [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html).

Comment: thanks, do I need to restart the server after editing the vhosts file?

Comment: Yes, every time you edit the server configuration, you must restart the server.