# how to configure xampp in windows if project files are not in root directory

Tags: apache, svn, path, xampp

i am using windows .my xampp is install in drive C ,firstly i worked here in my files

```
 C->xampp->htdocs->SVN data->php_clients->trunks->myproject
```

but than for **SVN** i copy paste my all files here now SVN Is configured here

```
D->SVN data->php_clients->trunks->myproject
```

i am testing my project locally i mean in localhost,firstly  it was in

```
 C->xampp->htdocs->SVN data->php_clients->trunks->myproject
```

so i was able to work ,test,update now i am suppose to work in files which is located here

```
 D->SVN data->php_clients->trunks->myproject
```

but problem is of xampp what is the nice and easy way so that i work here and work locally that is localhost

```
D->SVN data->php_clients->trunks->myproject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
go  here that is C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf 
open httpd.conf
Find This DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" Edit this to 
DocumentRoot "D:/SVN data/php_clients/trunks/myproject"
after that find this tag
<Directory> and make it like this 
<Directory "D:/SVN data/php_clients/trunks/myproject">
Restart Your Apache go to browser write http://localhost in address bar and see your app
```